# How to import a library into a web worker in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, node-modules, web-worker

I am trying to run a face detection process in the background of my React app using a web worker. I am using a library called `face-api.js` to do the face detection. But I'm unsure as to how to import this library to use in my `worker.js` file.

**worker.js**

```
    import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';
    
    this.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log("Message from worker.js");
      this.postMessage('Hello Main')   
    };
```

**TestComponent.js**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

function TestComponent() {

    useEffect(() => {
        const worker = new Worker('./workers/worker.js')
        worker.postMessage('Hello Worker')
        worker.onmessage = e => {
        console.log('Message received from worker:', e.data)
    }
    }
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Test Component </h1>
        </div>
    )
    }


export default TestComponent
```

I run this test code and I get the following error on chrome:

```
 /workers/worker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have tried using `require` to import the library which didn't work. I also tried declaring the worker as a module
`const worker = new Worker('./workers/worker.js', type: "module")`
This makes the error go away but then nothing works: the worker does not do what it is intended to do.

Please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using [Worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) as a webpack plugin for your web-worker?

Comment: Have you solved this? I run into the same issue

Comment: Did you try to use [useWorker](https://github.com/alewin/useWorker) library?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use {type:"module"} in the options of worker constructor for use "import" features in the worker file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker

> options Optional
> An object containing option properties that can be set when creating the object instance. Available properties are as follows:

> type: A DOMString specifying the type of worker to create. The value can be classic or module. If not specified, the default used is classic.

> credentials: A DOMString specifying the type of credentials to use for the worker. The value can be omit, same-origin, or include. If not specified, or if type is classic, the default used is omit (no credentials required).

> name: A DOMString specifying an identifying name for the DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope representing the scope of the worker, which is mainly useful for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `importScript()` in your service worker file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).